# How to move left right on touch and up down through accelerometer in Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

     public static float distanceTraveled;
     private Touch curTouch;
     public float speed;
     public float maxSpeed;
     public float maxSpeedConstant;

     //Virtual buttons left and right half of the screen
     private Rect leftHalf = new Rect(0F,0F,Screen.width/2,Screen.height);
     private Rect rightHalf = new Rect(Screen.width/2,0F,Screen.width/2,Screen.height);

     public void Update() {        
         distanceTraveled = transform.localPosition.x;
         }
     public void FixedUpdate() {
         Movement ();
     }
public void Movement() {

         //Accelerometer Control up/down
         Vector3 dirAcc = Vector3.zero;

         dirAcc.y = Input.acceleration.y*.5F;

         transform.Translate(0F,0F,dirAcc.y);

         if(Input.touchCount != 0){
             Vector2 curTouch = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
             if (leftHalf.Contains (curTouch)){
                 transform.Translate(-Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);

             }else{
                 if (rightHalf.Contains(curTouch)){
                     transform.Translate(Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);

                 }
             }
         }else{
             if(Input.touchCount == 0){
                 transform.Translate(Vector3.right*speed*Time.deltaTime);

             }            
         }        
     }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the play is **able to control the up/down movement of the character via accelerometer and right/left movement by touching the right/left side of the screen**.

With the above code the touch area does not matter the character will always move backwards and accelerometer input is entirely ignored. What bothers me is that the above code (accelerometer part only) worked with transform.Translate instead of rigidbody.AddForce. But from what I've read on the internet I'm going to need rigidbodies if I want collisions.

So any help or advice regarding code structure/syntax or solution towards my problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On first look for the up/ down movement you are trying to change the z value which is possibly the forward movement. Another issue could be for your calculation of the touch position. It is better to covert the touch position to the camera's viewport and check for the left or right positions. A simple implementation would be like this. Add this code to any object in the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerScript: MonoBehaviour {



    public void FixedUpdate ( ) {
        Movement ( );
    }
    public void Movement ( ) {
        //Accelerometer Control up/down
        Vector3 dirAcc = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 mousePosition = Vector3.zero;


#if UNITY_ANDROID
        dirAcc.y = Input.acceleration.y * .5F;

         if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint ( Input.touches[0].position );
        }
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
        if( Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.W ) ) {
            dirAcc = Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
            dirAcc = Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint ( Input.mousePosition );
        }
#endif
        if( mousePosition.x > 0 ) {
            if( mousePosition.x > 0.5f ) { // right side of the screen
                dirAcc += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else {
                dirAcc += Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        transform.Translate ( dirAcc );
    }
}
```

I have not tested this on a device.